# How to programmatically access the full source of the running JS file in a browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

I need to get the `sourceMapURL` or `debugId` embedded at the bottom of my bundled source code.

The script was included in a `<script src="..." />` tag. Can I read the full contents of this file without doing a separate network request?

If I didn't constraint myself to a script tag, could I do it another way?

Maybe a Chrome Extension could help?

Last resort would be to send the source code via `window.fooSourceCode='...'.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: For a frame in a stack trace, I want to show the code line and context.

Comment: Your browser's dev-tools already do that, though... and `console.trace()` simply writes the call-stack to the console: it doesn't expose it as structured data to in-page script.

Comment: I want to access it in code to manipulate it.

Comment: In runtime or before loading? You can change the code in dev tools

Comment: I need it at runtime.